# nodejs import from main/root of project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In node, I can import a module from the "main" or "root" of the project by doing the following:

```
require.main.require('mongodb')
```

Is there a way to do this with `import`? I cannot seem to find a way to do this, so maybe one doesn't exist.

Maybe something like this?

```
// Pseudo code:
import { MongoClient } from main 'mongodb'
```

When using a normal import:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
```

I get an error saying that it doesn't exist, however, it is in the root of the project.

> Cannot find module 'mongodb'

Comment: Try with [Path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

Comment: There is an open issue about this in the TypeScript repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19117

Comment: `require.main.require` works for me. I'm looking for something similar using `import`